# How to edit html content in Django forms?

Tags: html, django

Because I am not from English Naive country.
Default html content from Django form,  is not suitable for my country.
Could someone tell me how to edit html content in forms.py?
I just want to keep English variable for later SQL column settings, but change html content in form.

in forms.py

```py
class DjUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = DjUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

in html

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="註冊">
</form>
```

It showed all English content in html, like Username, Email Address etc..
The thing I needed is 使用者名稱, 電子信箱 etc.. The html contents I want to edit:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [attr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) for styling and naming you're form fields, it will go something like this:

```
class DjUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'my-class',
                'placeholder': '使用者名稱, 電子信箱',
            }))
```

also you will perhaps need to do some [localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/) for you're application.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to change html content(<x>content</x>), not placeholder.
And the things I want to change is in the inner class Meta, such as <label>Username:</label> into <label>使用者:</label>

Comment: Exactly, you can do it with `attrs`, or use some third party app like crispy forms.